# deploying ruby on rails app using capistrano - cap deploy:setup failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, capistrano

I've wasted a few days on this problem and I'm sure it's a simple solution, please help!
When I run `$ cap deploy:setup` from my user account on my laptop I get the errors I've pasted below. It seems that there's a problem with RVM, but I know that it's installed, and I've pre-installed all the gems my app will need as well. Has anyone else encountered similar errors? Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```
  * executing `deploy:setup'
  * executing "mkdir -p /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/ /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/releases /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/system /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/log /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/pids &&  chmod g+w /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/ /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/releases /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/system /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/log /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/pids"
    servers: ["arbiter.nullpointer.ca"]
    [arbiter.nullpointer.ca] executing command
 ** [out :: arbiter.nullpointer.ca] 
 ** [out :: arbiter.nullpointer.ca] $rvm_path (system_wide) does not exist.
*** [err :: arbiter.nullpointer.ca] /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm: line 154: __rvm_teardown: command not found
*** [err :: arbiter.nullpointer.ca] /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell: line 74: rvm: command not found
*** [err :: arbiter.nullpointer.ca] Error: RVM was unable to use 'default'
    command finished
failed: "rvm_path=system_wide /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c \"mkdir -p /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/ /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/releases /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/system /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/log /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/pids &&  chmod g+w /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/ /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/releases /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/system /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/log /usr/local/www/sites/arbiter.nullpointer.ca/public/shared/pids\"" on arbiter.nullpointer.ca
```

Comment: What version of RVM are you using? It may be worth updating since this issue seems related: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/586

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I'm using rvm 1.10.2.

Comment: it looks like a problem in your configuration, post the 'set's for rvm

Comment: This problem seems to have been resolved unexpectedly. Not quite sure what I did... but now I'm getting another error. I'll post a link to the post with the new error.

Comment: Here's my new error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252200/type-error-during-capistrano-deploysetup

Answer (score 15):

I just ran into this problem though my installation was complaining with:

```
out :: server]
** [out :: server] $rvm_path (/home/nebula/.rvm/) does not exist.
*** [err :: server] /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm: line 185: __rvm_teardown: command not found
*** [err :: server] /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm: line 52: /home/nebula/.rvm//scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
*** [err :: server] Error sourcing RVM!
*** [err :: server] Error: RVM was unable to use 'ruby-1.9.3-p392'
```

I am using rvm with a system wide install, (standard install to /usr/local/rvm).  Adding the following to my Capfile solved the issue:

```
set :rvm_type, :system
set :rvm_path, "/usr/local/rvm"
```

Comment: Indeed that worked! As a footnote, I will add that I first used `set :rvm_bin_path, "/usr/local/rvm/bin"`, and although this information was correct (I did have a bin folder containing the executable), this kept giving me the same error. When I changed the line to `set :rvm_path, "/usr/local/rvm"`it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Error shows: RVM was unable to use 'default' gemset. Means RVM can't find a gemset named 'default' to use. Check the following line in your deploy.rb

```
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'gemset-name-here'  => put a valid gemset here
```